# Why the value of variable is not getting checked correctly by the "if" statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to catch the element when the value of the input is null but the if statement isn't working.

```
for (let i = 0; i<esquema.length; i++){
    if (esquema[i].checked){
        console.log(esquema[i].value);
        if (esquema[i].value == null){
            console.log ("Actually null");
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be

```
null
Actually null
```

But instead of that i am getting

```
null
undefined
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It may be the string `'null'`, check `typeof`

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and the context of where this code is within your page and how it gets invoked.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, it was... Thank you!

Comment: If `esquema` is an HTML element, it will never have a `value` of `null`. It will have a `value` of `""` if it doesn't have a `value`, so the test should be: `if (esquema[i].value == "")`

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of an HTMLElement is either `undefined` if it is not an `<input>` (`<button>`, ...) element, or it is a string. As it is not `undefined` (as it logs `null`, and `null == undefined` would be true), it has to be `"null"` which would log `null` but would not be equal to `null`.

Most consoles do print `null` and `"null"` differently though, log both and compare the results to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your function, it works if the value being received is null. It wouldn't be checking the type of data but just match the value.

```
var esquema = [
  {
    checked: true,
    value: "None"
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: null
  }
];
for (let i = 0; i<esquema.length; i++){
    if (esquema[i].checked){
        console.log(esquema[i].value);
        if (esquema[i].value === null){
            console.log ("Actually null");
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, I assume that esquema is set of checkboxes and i am sure you wouldn't be able to set a value as "null". If the value is not added to the node, it would be "undefined" but not "null" in any case.